# Django 1.5 giving error 405 for simple form

Tags: django, authentication, http-status-code-405, create-view

I made a form for including Auth Groups. But when I post it I get a blank page (url /groups/) with an Error on terminal: **"POST /grupos/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0** This is so weird, when I give refresh I see the list of groups, with nothing added.

=== urls.py

```
    url(r'^groups/$', login_required(TemplateUtilsListView.as_view(model=Group)), name='group_list'),
url(r'^groups/add$', login_required(CreateView.as_view(model=Group, form_class=GroupForm, template_name='generic_insert.html')), name='group_create'),
```

=== forms.py ===

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Group
```

=== generic_insert.html ===

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action=".">
{% if form.visible_fields %}
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
<p>
    <label {% if field.field.required %}class="required-field"{% endif %}>{{ field.label }}:</label> 
    {{ field }}
        {% if field.errors %}
        <span class="error-list">{% for error in field.errors %}{{ error }}{% endfor %}</span>
        {% endif %}
        {% if field.help_text %}<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/help-icon.png" class="help-icon" title="{{ field.help_text }}">{% endif %}
</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<p><input type="submit" class="button" value="{% trans 'Salvar' %}" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean Django 1.4? Django 1.5 is not out yet.

Comment: It looks like you hit `grupos` when your POST should haved hit `grupos/add`. The error is probably there.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! It was missing an '/' after add, now it is hitting correct!
url(r'^groups/add/$', login_required(CreateView.as_view(model=Group, form_class=GroupForm, template_name='generic_insert.html')), name='group_create')

Comment: And Simeon, it is Django 1.5, the GIT development version.