# Django 1.6 Model Forms, AttributeError

Tags: python, django, forms, attributeerror, django-forms

**Django 1.6. Model Form problem. E-commerce.**

Hi there,

I'd really appreciate some help with my seemingly "oh-so-simple (yer-right)" problem. Noob to Django, just trying to get a customer application for a very basic e-commerce website I'm making. The plan is, at this stage, to be able for customers to fill in their name and address details for their delivery. I've read so-so-so many articles online, and on here, with slightly differing approaches, none of which are exactly the (seemingly simple :-)) thing I want. I'm now totally confused...!

My questions are:
1) What does this error mean, and how do I get round it?
2) Is my code right to display a model form?
...and the bonus...
3) Is there a better (read simple) way of making an name and address collector thingy for the site?

I have a model, from which I would think the best plan would be to generate a model form. However, the error I'm now getting (the millionth error of the day) is

```
AttributeError at /customers/

'list' object has no attribute 'resolve'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/customers/
Django Version:     1.6.5
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'list' object has no attribute 'resolve'

Exception Location:     /home/david/.virtualenvs/winestore/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve, line 339
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode


    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    ~~~~~ Other Fields ~~~~~~

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.email)

class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', ~~~~other fields~~~~~]
```

urls.py (the main project urls.py has url(r'^customers/', include('customers.urls')), to point it here).

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from customers.views import CustomerForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', CustomerForm.as_view, name ='add_customer')),
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from customers.models import Customer, CustomerForm

class CustomerForm(View):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        template_name ='add_customer.html'

        def get_success_url (self):
            return HttpResponse('success.html')
```

the template add_customer.html

```
<h1>Add Your details please</h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
<ul>
    {{ form.as_ul }}
</ul>
<input id="save_customer" type="submit" value="Save" />

</form>
<a href="{% url "/" %}">Back home</a>
```

I had a forms.py ,but read it wasn't necessary for a model form (?).

Any help much appreciated.

**Edit_V_2:** My thanks to Peter and Luis, who respectively noted a trailing comma in the urls.py and that it should be CustomerForm.as_view(), not CustomerForm.as_view.

The page now loads! But is sadly blank. So, so close...!

**Edit 3:** The server error given is a 405 error. According to this ([Django 1.5 giving error 405 for simple form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316709/django-1-5-giving-error-405-for-simple-form)) the problem may be somewhere in the urls.py addresses.

Comment: You probably had a longer traceback: could you include the rest of it?

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for that. Peter (below) noted a trailing comma in the urls.py file, deleting that changed the error message to TypeError at /customers/

as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given). Do you still want the traceback of the old error?!? (Glad to share... :-))

Comment: No need, sounds like the problem is fixed. Since your first problem (two problems!) have been fixed, it's probably a good idea to accept the answer, then try and solve the new (third) problem on your own. If you can't you can start a new question. It's a good way to avoid being a ["chameleon question"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `urls.py` file is exactly as shown, you have a typo in it:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', CustomerForm.as_view, name ='add_customer')),
```

The trailing comma turns the variable from a `patterns` object into a 1-length tuple of the `patterns` object, eg:

```
>>> foo = 1,
>>> type(foo)
<type 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! That's changed the error to: <code>TypeError at /customers/

as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/customers/
Django Version:  1.6.5
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  

as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Exception Location:  /home/david/.virtualenvs/winestorefour/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 112 </code>

Comment: `as_view` ... shouldn't view `as_view()` like in `TemplateView`?

Comment: Whoa! Luis! Now the page loads! It's still blank, so something else is wrong, but it now loads.. Thanks. Thanks. Thanks.